# Dynamic Android TextView size

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a RelativeLayout where I have 2 TextView side by side (the left one it's the field name and the right one it's the value).

What I need it's to have the left textview always showing the full field name and the other TextView using the remaining space in that line to print the field value. Imagining that I have a field named "Field" with the value "That's a huge value!" and the remaining width of screen just leaves us with space to have half of the field value I need to have it like this:

| Field: That's a huge v... |

If, for some reason, the field name would fill the entire screen I don't event want to appear the value (I have another way of solving that).

I'm trying to find an adaptive way to do this (for any field and any value) but I can't find the right settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, the answer is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FieldHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH:"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Value lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggT"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could easily achieve that with a LinearLayout and layout weights. Any special reason you need RelativeLayout?

Comment: With LianearLayout yes, but without weights

Comment: Sorry, my comment was intended for the question, not your answer.